# Disable "Correct to:" option with SWI-Prolog modules

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

So according to the documentation, predicates not included in a `module` directive should not be visible outside of the source file where they are defined.

Let's say have this file animals.pro:

```
:- module(animals, [mammal/1]).

mammal(rhino).
mammal(whale).

insect(fly).
insect(mantis).
```

And I do this...

```
:- use_module(animals).

insect(X).
```

It prompts me with:

```
Correct to: "animals:insect(X)"?
```

How do I disable that sort of prompting? I don't want `insect` to be visible at all. Period.

Comment: This only happens because you are at the top level, and it is trying to be too helpful (if you wrapped the call to `insect/1` inside a predicate you will not get the prompt). I also don't know of any method for _completely_ hiding a private predicate -- you can always pick it up from the calling context using the `module:private_pred` notation. Why is that bothering you?

Comment: It happens because modules are a **predicate-prefixing mechanism** first that doubles as a poor encapsulation mechanism.

Comment: @Paulo Yea, does seem to be poor at encapsulation.

Comment: @Boris Regarding why it's bothering me, please see comment to your answer below.

Answer (score 4):

After taking a precursory look at the SWI-Prolog source code, I don't think there is a straight-forward way to disable the "Correct to:" prompt when you are querying from the top level. I might be mistaken.

However, the prompt only pops up if you try querying the "private" predicate directly. If it is called from another predicate, you won't see anything and you will get the exception you expect:

```
?- use_module(animals).
true.

?- assertz(( foo(X) :- insect(X) )).
true.

?- foo(X).
ERROR: foo/1: Undefined procedure: insect/1
   Exception: (8) insect(_G1431) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
?- insect(X).
Correct to: "animals:insect(X)"? no
ERROR: residue_vars/2: Undefined procedure: insect/1
   Exception: (7) insect(_G3328) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

As I said in the comment above, you can always pick up a private predicate from a module by qualifying it explicitly. Continuing with the above example:

```
?- assertz(( bar(X) :- animals:insect(X) )).
true.

?- bar(X).
X = fly ;
X = mantis.
```

You can of course read the [documentation on modules](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modules) yourself.

As for why it is like this: well, it is a design decision I guess. If I remember correctly, Python does the same -- you cannot really hide the implementation if the caller knows what to look for. Is your intention to use this for "hiding the implementation", Java-OOP style?

Comment: Thanks Boris. Wrapping every single predicate that is *meant* to be private isn't really practical (unless I'm missing something). The reason why I want to hide it is because I'm automating unit test creation using `log_file/1`. The people using it should only be able to log predicates that are *exposed*, so to speak.

Comment: @Ash I wouldn't suggest you wrap anything anyway. I just wanted to show that _only when_ you try to evaluate a "private" module predicate _directly_ from the top level would you see this. BTW, what is `log_file/1`? I couldn't find any definition of this anywhere. Maybe you should ask a new question and be a bit more specific about your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use Logtalk instead of modules. You can run it not only with SWI-Prolog but also with eleven more Prolog systems. Logtalk enforces encapsulation, preventing calling of non-public predicates. For a quick experiment you can do (in SWI-Prolog), assuming the module in your post is saved in an `animals.pl` file:

```
?- pack_install(logtalk).
true.

?- use_module(library(logtalk)).
true.

?- {animals}.
% [ /Users/pmoura/Desktop/animals.pl loaded ]
% (0 warnings)
true.

?- animals::insect(X).
ERROR: predicate_declaration `insect/1' does not exist
...
```

In this quick experiment, Logtalk simply compiled your `animals` module as a Logtalk object. For serious usage, and to take advantage of all Logtalk features (e.g. interfaces/protocols), is usually simple to convert existing modules to objects. In your case:

```
:- object(animals)

    :- public(mammal/1).

    mammal(rhino).
    mammal(whale).

    insect(fly).
    insect(mantis).

:- end_object.
```

The default extension for Logtalk source files is `.lgt`. If you save the object version in a `animals.lgt` file, you can then loaded it the same way using the `{}/1` shortcut to `logtalk_load/1`.

You can still use modules together with objects, including calling module predicates from objects and sending messages to objects from modules, if necessary.

P.S. Despite the use of the `use_module/1` directive above, Logtalk is not implemented as a module. The directive is only used as a loading mechanism for the pack.

Comment: Are these `object` directives meant to go in `animals.pl`? I tried inserting your second block of code in `animals.pl` and running it but it gives me a `ERROR: animals.pl:1:2: Syntax error: Operator priority clash
ERROR: animals.pl:11:
        catch/3: Undefined procedure: end_object/0`

Comment: @Ash From the error message I would guess that you tried to consult the file instead of using the `{}/1` shortcut to the `logtalk_load/1` predicate (as in my post). Either load your `animals.pl` file as-is using the goal `{animals}` **or** save the object version of your code in a `animals.lgt` file and load it using the same goal.